# What does "dwarf2_read_address: Corrupted DWARF expression." mean?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gdb

I'm trying to do a little debugging in my iPhone project, and whenever i try to print out an object to see its description in one specific method i get this message in gdb:

> "dwarf2_read_address: Corrupted DWARF
>   expression."

Does anyone know why this happens and how i would go about fixing it so that i can inspect my variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this is a known bug in gdb, fixed in later versions (6.7 and above). I've found a reference to it in [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=439234) bugzilla thread, but that's all I managed to find that's in any manner useful. Try updating your GDB installation.

Comment: I don't know if I can do that with xcode, I haven't seen the issue in a while though so it's not a problem currently.